# Docker with node.js - Error: .ngxrc not found

Tags: node.js, docker

I have created a docker image with the following docker file:

```
FROM node:current-alpine3.14

#install the http-server
RUN npm install -g ngx

# define working directory in docker linux environment
WORKDIR /app

# copy the builded app
COPY /dist/app /app

# start the http-server in the working directory
CMD ngx start
```

If i run the docker image with the following command:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

i got the following error:

```
Error Error: .ngxrc not found
    at OptionManager._callee2$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/lib/option-manager.js:184:23)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ngx/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:30:13
```

I have not found infos about the error in the web.

Have somebody an idea what i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have no [.ngxrc](https://github.com/kaelzhang/ngx/blob/master/sample/.ngxrc) config copied over to your image.

Copy this file in your root project folder and modify your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine3.14

#install the http-server
RUN npm install -g ngx


# define working directory in docker linux environment
WORKDIR /app

COPY .ngxrc .

# copy the builded app
COPY /dist/app /app

# start the http-server in the working directory
CMD ngx start
```

Rebuild your image and run the container, and the error should be gone.
of course you should modify the `.ngxrc` to fit your requirements.